# Could Facebook Analytics Notifiction Campaign send dynamic content?

Tags: push-notification, notifications, facebook-analytics

In the Facebook Analytics Notification Campaign, could we send dynamic content in the push notification or in-app notification?

Comment: The team would be interested to know where you'd want to source the dynamic content from (user properties an event's parameters or somewhere else?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported by the product at this time.